# What is the best method to calculate the square root when I know that the root is always an integer?

Tags: numerical-methods

I have been through the wikipedia page, but wanted to know if there was a preferred (most efficient) method when there is an exact solution to find?

Comment: binary search it takes O(logN)

Comment: How big a number? Do you have a calculator or is this mental arithmetic?

Comment: You can immediately tell the number of digits of $\sqrt{N}$ using the number of digits on $N$ and by looking at the number of digits of $N$. Like Henry says, the optimal method may be different if you have more information for the size of $N$; there are very fast algorithms for small $N$, e.g., $N < 10^4$.

Comment: Have you already tried http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_square_root#Using_only_integer_division ?

Comment: Typically I am talking about solutions that are a maximum of 2^128 which is obviously very large. I would be doing this using a computer program running on a very low power device and am trying to make this as efficient as possible.